# Count Elements in Image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following image: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g7Bp.jpg)

[image]

I'm trying to count al these colored cells and draw a circle around them.
I really don't now how I can use `SelectComponents` for this image. And `EdgeDetect` has the following result: [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2jOx.jpg)

[image]

Maybe some tips or examples.

Greetings

Comment: If you just want information about the components (centroid, caliper length), `ComponentMeasurements` should be more useful than `SelectComponents`

Comment: No, I want to know how you can use these functions to count the cell (examples)

Comment: Have you looked at `MorphologicalComponents` ?

Comment: I have an impression that this is not the original image. What is the *very* original image you start from?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: If you are able to use `colorize` it seems like you already have all the components isolated and don't need to do image processing. If you post your code to get to this point I think it would be very simple to count the number of components.

Answer (score 17):

I will follow algorithm described in [**the following blog**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/), but will have to modify some parameters for your case. You can also drop `FillingTransform` from the blog code because you don't have holes in your regions.

```
rbc = ImageCrop[   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOJps.png"], {300, 340}];

b = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[Binarize[rbc, .81]], 50];
distT = DistanceTransform[b, Padding -> 0];
marker = MaxDetect[ImageAdjust[distT], 0.02];
w = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[b, 3], marker, 
   Method -> "Rainfall"];

cells = SelectComponents[w, "Count", 500 < # < 3000 &];
measures = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   cells, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];
Show[rbc, 
 Graphics[{Blue, Circle @@ # & /@ (measures[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]), 
   MapThread[Text, {measures[[All, 2, 3]], measures[[All, 2, 1]]}]}]]
```

[image]

Then bare number of circled cells can be computed with

```
measures // Length
```

> 16

Comment: I have used the blog you referred to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Glenn please register your account.  Then you will be able to use the 41 "reputation" points you already have to post comments.