# Count flowers in an image

Tags: image-processing

How to count all flower in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B30S.jpg) by using *Mathematica*?

[image]

It is possible to detect red objects and then remove background?

I guess [this blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) may be useful. and [this question, "Count Elements in Image"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15921/30288)

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Comment: I get 251 with `ComponentMeasurements[
  MorphologicalComponents[ChanVeseBinarize[img, Red]], 
  "Count"] // Length`

Comment: @bobthechemist there are more flowers than 251 :)  `ComponentMeasurements[
  MorphologicalComponents[
   ChanVeseBinarize[img, Red, MaxIterations -> 1]], "Count"] // Length`. I get 317.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is what I get.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3S3Q.jpg"];

red = Fold[ImageSubtract, #[[1]], Rest[#]] &@ColorSeparate[img]
```

[image]

```
b = Binarize[red]
```

[image]

```
pos = ComponentMeasurements[b, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
Length[pos]
```

> 633

**Fine Tuning**

Since the flowers in the top left corner are comparatively dull in colour, they are not properly identified. In such case a segment wise fine tuning may be helpful.

Consider a $300 \times 300$ block at top left corner. The previous method give 13 flower in this region.

```
im2 = ImageTake[img, {0, 300}, {0, 300}];

red = Fold[ImageSubtract, #[[1]], Rest[#]] &@ColorSeparate[im2]
b = Binarize[%];
pos = ComponentMeasurements[b, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
Length[pos]
```

> 13

Now we do a manual fine tuning by eliminating other colors.

```
im3 = ColorReplace[im2, Green, 0.3];
MorphologicalComponents[im3] // Colorize;
ColorReplace[%, DominantColors[%]] // Binarize;
fls = ComponentMeasurements[%, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
Length[fls]
```

> 92

```
Show[im2, Graphics[{Red, Circle[#, 10] & /@ fls[[All, 2, 1]],
                    Black, Circle[#, 10] & /@ pos[[All, 2, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

So our count increases by `(92-13) = 79`.

You might want to use this method for the whole image. In that case it will consider the lady as a lot of flowers and that would be 'mathematically' incorrect.

Comment: +1. but there are more flowers,  `Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Black, Thick, 
   Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
    ComponentMeasurements[
      ImageMultiply[img, b], {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[
     All, 2]]}]]` see [here](http://imgur.com/a/nprwX)

Comment: I agree. The pale red flowers are really tricky to pick. You may have to do some manual scanning in some parts.