# Multiple object detection and tracking in images

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, code-review

> The code below:
>
> 1. reads in a number of png images, where the background is dark and objects of interest (here 3) are bright dots
> 2. determines in each image the coordinates and other information about the objects
> 3. tracks the objects by using `Nearest`

Single image (reduced size, cropped) with 3 tiny bright objects (at upper corners and lower center):

[image]

Pixels of a single object:

[image]

*The code below can only be used if the number of objects in each image is the same.*

As output the objects' coordinates are printed before and after tracking.

9 test images (zipped) are located here: http://bit.ly/28J56Pd

The notebook file which contains the code can be downloaded here: http://goo.gl/WhS7eP

> My question is: **Where can the code be improved?**
>
> Especially: **How can I combine all `ComponentMeasurement` calls and
>   assign the results to the set of used arrays** (now in single command
>   lines)?

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], Dynamic[imageDir]}];

SetDirectory[imageDir];
dirBase = FileNameTake[imageDir];

(*read in file names and determine number of files*)

fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numFiles = Length[fNames];

(*find number of objects in first image*)

i = 1;
image = Import[fNames[[i]]];
t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];

binImage = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, t], 8];
newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage];

numObjects = Length@ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]];

(*define arrays*)

coordinates = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects, 2}];
threshold = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
equivalentDiskRadius = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
totalIntensity = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
meanIntensity = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
standardDeviationIntensity = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
boundingBoxArea = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];
numPixels = Array[0 &, {numFiles, numObjects}];

(*find coordinates and other relevant data of each object in first frame*)

i = 1;
coordinates[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]];
threshold[[i, All]] = t;
equivalentDiskRadius[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "EquivalentDiskRadius"][[All, 2]];
totalIntensity[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "TotalIntensity"][[All, 2]];
meanIntensity[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "MeanIntensity"][[All, 2]];
standardDeviationIntensity[[i]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "StandardDeviationIntensity"][[All, 
   2]];
boundingBoxArea[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "BoundingBoxArea"][[All, 2]];
numPixels[[i, All]] = 
  ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Count"][[All, 2]];

Print[i, " ", coordinates[[i, All]], "\n"];

(*loop over all images*) 

Do[

  image = Import[fNames[[i]]];
  t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];
  binImage = 
   DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, t], 
    8];(*8 has to be manually set*);
  newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage];

  coordinates[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]];
  threshold[[i, All]] = t;
  equivalentDiskRadius[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "EquivalentDiskRadius"][[All, 2]];
  totalIntensity[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "TotalIntensity"][[All, 2]];
  meanIntensity[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "MeanIntensity"][[All, 2]];
  standardDeviationIntensity[[i]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "StandardDeviationIntensity"][[All,
     2]];
  boundingBoxArea[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "BoundingBoxArea"][[All, 2]];
  numPixels[[i, All]] = 
   ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Count"][[All, 2]];

  Print[i, " ", coordinates[[i, All]]];

  (*sort coordinate order according to nearest neighbors, so that objects are tracked*)

  (* This is wrong: order = Flatten@Nearest[coordinates[[i - 1, All]] -> Automatic][coordinates[[i, All]]];*)
  order = Flatten@Nearest[coordinates[[i, All]] -> Automatic][coordinates[[i - 1, All]]];
  coordinates[[i, All]] = coordinates[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  threshold[[i, All]] = threshold[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  equivalentDiskRadius[[i, All]] = 
   equivalentDiskRadius[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  totalIntensity[[i, All]] = totalIntensity[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  meanIntensity[[i, All]] = meanIntensity[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  standardDeviationIntensity[[i]] = 
   standardDeviationIntensity[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  boundingBoxArea[[i, All]] = boundingBoxArea[[i, #]] & /@ order;
  numPixels[[i, All]] = numPixels[[i, #]] & /@ order;

  Print[i, " ", coordinates[[i, All]], "\n"],

  {i, 2, numFiles}
  ];

1 {{600.924,1321.05},{1282.57,1319.71},{927.97,726.014}}


2 {{601.472,1320.6},{1282.83,1320.66},{928.494,726.171}}

2 {{601.472,1320.6},{1282.83,1320.66},{928.494,726.171}}


3 {{601.599,1320.62},{1283.29,1321.66},{928.725,726.025}}

3 {{601.599,1320.62},{1283.29,1321.66},{928.725,726.025}}


4 {{1284.07,1322.6},{601.375,1320.79},{929.205,724.945}}

4 {{601.375,1320.79},{1284.07,1322.6},{929.205,724.945}}


5 {{1284.84,1323.69},{600.729,1321.26},{929.304,723.538}}

5 {{600.729,1321.26},{1284.84,1323.69},{929.304,723.538}}


6 {{1285.88,1324.76},{599.797,1321.9},{929.635,721.943}}

6 {{599.797,1321.9},{1285.88,1324.76},{929.635,721.943}}


7 {{1287.23,1325.46},{598.597,1322.92},{930.251,720.146}}

7 {{598.597,1322.92},{1287.23,1325.46},{930.251,720.146}}


8 {{1288.29,1325.99},{596.995,1324.19},{930.652,718.686}}

8 {{596.995,1324.19},{1288.29,1325.99},{930.652,718.686}}


9 {{595.348,1325.49},{1289.63,1326.32},{931.156,717.095}}

9 {{595.348,1325.49},{1289.63,1326.32},{931.156,717.095}}
```

Plot of the tracks:

```
ListPlot[# & /@ Transpose[coordinates], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10], Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {{"y (m)", ""}, {"x (m)", ""}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: http://goo.gl/Niy2B6 is not working with "It was found to be violating our Terms of Service"

Comment: now it should work ... http://bit.ly/28J56Pd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can the code be improved?

First of all: Try to avoid loops (`Do`, `For`, `While`) where possible - they're usually much more verbose than functional alternatives.

Second: Read the documentation. `ComponentMeasurements` can take a list of measurements, and will then return a list of values for each component.

Third: Use functions to encapsulate units of code.

For example, this function takes an image filename, finds components in the image and returns a list of measurements for each component:

```
Clear[getComponents]
getComponents[file_] := Module[{image, t, binImage},
  image = Import[file];
  t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];
  binImage = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, t], 8];
  Sow[t];
  ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[binImage], image},
    {"IntensityCentroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "TotalIntensity", 
     "MeanIntensity", "StandardDeviationIntensity", "BoundingBoxArea",
      "Count"}][[All, 2]]
  ]
```

You can then use:

```
files = FileNames["some folder\\*.png"];

getComponents /@ files
```

to execute this function for all images in that folder. This will return a multidimensional array, with the indices *[frame index, component index, measurement index]*.

You can use transpose to get the measurement index in front, and assign it to a list of symbols:

```
{intensityCentroid, equivalentDiskRadius, totalIntensity, meanIntensity, 
 standardDeviationIntensity, boundingBoxArea, count} = 
 Transpose[getComponents /@ files, {2, 3, 1}]
```

now `intensityCentroid` contains a 2d-array of intensity centroids (first index for the frame, second index for the component), `equivalentDiskRadius` contains a 2d-array of radii and so on.

You'll notice that we're missing the threshold - that's not a measurement, and it doesn't fit into our neat array structure. So I returned it using `Sow`, and I can get the values that were sowed in each call using `Reap`, so this line:

```
{{intensityCentroid, equivalentDiskRadius, totalIntensity, 
    meanIntensity, standardDeviationIntensity, boundingBoxArea, 
    count}, {thresholds}} = 
  Reap[Transpose[getComponents /@ files, {2, 3, 1}]];
```

I didn't reorder the components using `Nearest` above, to keep the code simple. It's not hard to add that, though:

```
Clear[getComponents, reorderComponents]
reorderComponents[components_, expectedPositions_] := Module[{indices},
  indices = (Nearest[expectedPositions -> Automatic] /@ 
      components[[All, 1]])[[All, 1]];
  components[[indices]]]

trackingCenters = {};
getComponents[file_] := Module[{image, t, binImage, components},
  image = Import[file];
  t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];
  binImage = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, t], 8];
  Sow[t];
  components = 
   ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[binImage], image},
     {"IntensityCentroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "TotalIntensity", 
      "MeanIntensity", "StandardDeviationIntensity", 
      "BoundingBoxArea", "Count"}][[All, 2]];

  If[trackingCenters === {}, trackingCenters = components[[All, 1]]];
  reorderComponents[components, trackingCenters]
  ]
```

Comment: This is great ...  I will test you code earliest this evening or tomorrow. I am recording images with a 4Megapixels (1000Hz) Photron camera (CMOS). In the experiment (a radio frequency plasma discharge) I illuminate micron sized spherical particles with a sheet of laser light and observe the reflected light under 90 degrees.) As you see with the upper code I can only track particles if the number per image is constant. Important will be to develop a tracking code if the number varies (single particle appear or disappear) - as e.g. trackpy (Python) does. Do you have experience in this field?

Comment: Perfect, both parts: object detection alone and in the second part combined with tracking work very well.

Comment: I found some problems and would like to ask you for help. Here are some images http://tinyurl.com/jm4uuhy where 3 objects are moving. Somehow `reorderComponents` is not giving the correct assignments. With my upper code (see correction: `order = Flatten@Nearest[coordinates[[i, All]] -> Automatic][coordinates[[i-1, All]]];` ) I plotted the trajectories (subfolder analysis). I used `DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, t], 1];`.

Answer (score 1):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkNTj.png"];
pos = ComponentMeasurements[img// Binarize,
        {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2, 1]];
Length[pos]
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Circle[#, 10]} & /@ pos]]
```

> 3

[image]

You might be interested in [Count flowers in an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117712/count-flowers-in-an-image) and [Count Elements in Image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15921/count-elements-in-image).

For your complete folder,

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Table[img[n] = Import["image_" <> ToString[n] <> ".png"];
      pos[n] = ComponentMeasurements[img[n] // Binarize,
           {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2, 1]];
      Show[img[n], Graphics[{Red, Circle[#, 50]} & /@ pos[n]], ImageSize -> 200]
,{n, 9}]
```

Comment: This code is very interesting and helpful ... a memory problem could be that my image sets consist of about 3000 images, each 4 Megapixel.

Comment: then I would suggest using `img` instead of `img[n]`. You don't need to store all the images.