# Counting dots/circles in an image

Tags: image-processing

I'm testing to see if I can count/draw circles around dots I drew on a piece of paper, this research is for my thesis as I want to count the amount of pinholes in a composite laminate. I tried several methods that were already given in several forums.

The code I use is:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/Wu7pSBY.jpg"];
i = GaussianFilter[FillingTransform[img], 15];
b = Binarize[i];
d = DistanceTransform[b, Padding -> 0];
m = MaxDetect[ImageAdjust[d, 0.2]];
w = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[b, 3], m, Method -> "Rainfall"];
s = SelectComponents[w, "Count", 20 < # < 10000 &];
ms = ComponentMeasurements[
   s, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];
Show[seimg, 
 Graphics[{Blue, Circle @@ # & /@ (ms[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]), 
   MapThread[Text, {ms[[All, 2, 3]], ms[[All, 2, 1]]}]}]]
```

I have zero to none idea what this all does, but the results are this (click for full size):

[image]

The only thing I want it to do is draw circles around the dots and count them.
Can anyone help out?

Comment: All you need is Binarize, ColorNegatve and ComponentMeasurements to find the centroids. Please read up on these. Using code you don't understand is not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Elements in Image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15921/8070) and [Count flowers in an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117712/8070) (which is a duplicate of the first one)

Comment: Try studying each line of the code by remove the semi-colons one at a time on each.  Just look at the first two, remove semi-colon on the GaussianFilter.  See what the output is.  Then study the help:  Type GaussianFilter, place cursor on it, press the "i" icon and study the help.  Do that slowly with each command, learn what's happening then have what I think is a good chance of not only understanding what's happening but improving it. :)

Comment: Thank you all so much for the respons, I'll experiment with the lines and will study the help.

Comment: See also [How to count number of small dots in a picture](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100957/how-to-count-number-of-small-dots-in-a-picture)

Answer (score 6):

I think I have a solid way now to count them, my code is:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/Wu7pSBY.jpg"];
b = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[Binarize[img]], 50];
c = ComponentMeasurements[
   b, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];
Show[b, Graphics[{Red, Circle @@ # & /@ (c[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]), 
   MapThread[Text, {c[[All, 2, 3]], c[[All, 2, 1]]}]}]]
c // Length
```

This resulted in this:

[image]

Thanks for the help everyone!